# 'Namespace' is undefined when trying to call asmx method from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asmx, scriptmanager

I'm attempting to use jQuery to access a method in an asmx webservice. When I try to execute the below jquery call, I get an error 'MyNameSpace' is undefined.

jquery call to webservice:

```
  MyNameSpace.MyWebService.MyMethod(parameter, function (e) { alert('Success') }, function (e) { alert('Failure') });
```

scriptmanager:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
     <Services>
       <asp:ServiceReference path="MyWebService.asmx" />
     </Services>
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

MyWebService.asmx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Script.Services;


namespace MyNameSpace{
    [ScriptService]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    //[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        [WebMethod]
        public void MyMethod(string parameter)
        {
            //do some cool stuff


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with my .asmx file and the fact that I had moved it into a different folder. To fix my .asmx file, i right click on it and selected view markup. The class property was set to the wrong class so my scriptmanager couldn't load it.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, I also fell foul of "I'll just tidy that up"...

If you have changed the assembly root namespace, ensure that you edit the reference in the 'inherits' property of the the asmx file itself.  This isn't always obvious as VS doesn't show the contents of this file.

btw. temporarily Setting InlineScript="True" on the Script Manager will cause the application to throw an actual exception in these cases, which makes it a lot easier to figure out what's going wrong.

*(Although the OP had already answered their own question, I thought this experience worth adding for future reference.)*

Comment: Thanks for the InlineScript tip. After I set it to True, the real error was displayed. (I was missing a dll).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add a different answer than what was given above. This is an edge case that I had encountered just recently.

In my case, I have been hit with timing issues when my scripts are being loaded. This means, on Google Chrome, my script loads fine and is able to access the WebService methods. However, on IE11, my script fails to load, because it is loaded before ScriptManager is loaded in, and thus, IE11 can't see the namespace in order to access the WebService methods.

There are 2 possible suggestions on how to fix this timing issue. Both are not reliably the silver bullets for this rare issue.

#### Adding ScriptReference to the ScriptManager

As mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx):

> #### Registering Custom Script
>
> Use the ScriptManager control to manage resources that you have created for controls that participate in partial-page updates. Resources include scripts, styles, hidden fields, and arrays. The Scripts collection of the ScriptManager control contains a ScriptReference object for each script that is available to the browser. You can specify the scripts declaratively or programmatically.
>   The ScriptManager control also exposes registration methods that you can use to manage client script and hidden fields programmatically. When you are registering script or hidden fields that support partial-page updates, you must call registration methods of the ScriptManager control. (To register scripts that are not needed for partial-page updates, you use methods of the ClientScriptManager class.)

In other words, you have to add your scripts like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="BackgroundService.asmx" />
    </Services>
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/customScript.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/test_script_for_lulz.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

This is so the ScriptManager is able to reference your scripts when it is being loaded.

#### Adding Your Scripts After ScriptManager

The other way of doing this is to add your scripts after ScriptManager, inside your `<form runat="server">` element, like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="BackgroundService.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<%-- Your scripts come after ScriptManager --%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/test_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/lulz_script_again.js"></script>
```

This way, your scripts are then loaded after ScriptManager finishes loading, due to the way the markup language is read by the browser.

Again, no guarantees on which solution is the better than the other. It's a timing issue that I've encountered, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to note is that make sure that you are passing the parameters with the correct data type. The same issue happens to me where I forgot to convert the array into a string that the server-side method accepts.